# Cannot loop jQuery dialogbox in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having problems to setup a jQuery dialogbox in a specific array using the following div ID code in my index file:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

And now to generate a dialogbox from an array that is placed in a javascript file from a subfolder with the following code:

```js
"pins": [{
    "name": "A",
    "status": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "src": "http://test/images/pins/up.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "status": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "src": "http://test/images/pins/up.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "status": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "src": "http://test/images/pins/down.png"
  }
];


var pins = "<div id=dialog ></div>";
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });

  $("src").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

I want to initialize 3 dialogs with an onclick function on the image-pin url, load the name-value as the title of the box and the status-value as text within the box.

I have already tried a hundred ways which did not lead to success.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.. Are you want to initialize 3 dialogs?

Comment: Thank you. I already placed an update.

Comment: Ok. You are generating just one static dialog. Where is the loop?

Comment: Like so? for (i in 1:length(mydata$x) ) {    
  if(src>=0) {
    src[i++]
  } else {
    src$y[i] <- 0
  }    
}
I indeed missed the thought of placing a loop but the onclick doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is, generate `img` for each item in the array, bind `click` event on it. When the user will click on it, you will replace the `img`'s src in the `#dialog` to the `src` of the image who clicked. Finally, open the dialog.

If I understand you correctly, it should be something like this:

```js
var pins = [{
    "name": "A",
    "status": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "src": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/633276/pexels-photo-633276.jpeg?h=350&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "status": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "src": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/633501/pexels-photo-633501.jpeg?h=350&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "status": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "src": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/633548/pexels-photo-633548.jpeg?h=350&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
  }
];

$.each(pins, function(i, pin) {
  $('body').append('<img src="' + pin.src + '" class="src" />');
});

$(function() {
  var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });

  $("img").on("click", function() {
    dialog.find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.src {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

#dialog img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog">
  <img />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mosh. I did some tests with your version and got it working in the setup that I had in mind. Cheers

Comment: My pleasure  . Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/303669) the answer so it will be help to other peoples.